# How to hide the manufacturer of the ethernet information in a raspberry

Tags: networking, wireless

How to hide the manufacturer or supplier of the network card of the IP scanner, I need to hide, delete or change the name of the manufacturer of a raspberry.

[image: network view]

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer name you are seeing comes from the list of registered [Organizationally unique identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_unique_identifier).

For example, you can use this [OUI Lookup](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html) tool from Wireshark to see that B8:27:EB is registered to the "Raspberry Pi Foundation".

It is not too hard to spoof a MAC Address (i.e. change it to anything you like), but what you want to change it to depends on why you want to change it. Some options include:

- If you are releasing your own products based on Raspberry Pi boards, but don't want to use the RPi MACs, perhaps you could purchase a block of MAC addresses from the [IEEE Registration Authority](https://standards.ieee.org/products-services/regauth/index.html)
- You could use a locally administered address by setting `b1` to 1 in the first octet of the address. This [blog](https://packetsdropped.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/mac-address-universally-or-locally-administered-bit-and-individualgroup-bit/) explains the idea, and the wiki page for [MAC Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) has a good picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#/media/File:MAC-48_Address.svg). E.g. you might want to just modify the RPi's MAC from B**8**:27:EB:xx:yy:zz to B**A**:27:EB:xx:yy:zz. However, some networks and network administrators might not like this.
- You could change it to squat on another company's OUI range (e.g. if you changed the mac to be 00:00:00:xx:yy:zz the manufacturer would appear as Xerox corp). However, this might lead to problems and it is not a very nice thing to do (unless there is a good reason).

***Side note***

There is sometimes a good reason to "clone" a MAC address, especially in wireless networking. For example, if you are using a WiFi bridge to connect computer A to the network Z, by bridging computer A's ethernet port to the Wifi network, the network looks like this:

```
Regular Bridging Scenario
=========================

Computer              WiFi         ^    =radio=   ^          WiFi                 Computer
   A                  Bridge      / \            / \       Access Point              B
+------+              +-----+      |              |         +-----+               +------+
|      |MAC A    MAC x|     |MAC Q |              |   MAC P |     | MAC y   MAC B |      |
|      +--------------+     +------+              +---------+     +---------------+      |
|      | Eth      Eth |     |   Antenna          Antenna    |     | Eth       Eth |      |
+------+              +-----+                               +-----+               +------+
                                                                               ^
                                                                               |
                                                                Traffic from "Computer A" shows
                                                                up using WiFi Bridge's wireless 
                                                                interface MAC Q (this is how it 
                                                                normally works).
```

All of the different MAC addresses are not that important, but the WiFi bridge in a standard configuration like this will replace the MAC addresses it hears on the ethernet side with its own MAC when communicating wirelessly (and will undo them when traffic is coming back the other way). The means that when Computer A talks to Computer B, the frames Computer B receives will have MAC-Q instead of MAC-A

However, if Computer B has some restriction that it will only work if communicated to with the MAC address from Computer A this setup will fail. In this instance, the WiFi bridge could be configured to "clone" the MAC address of computer A (either dynamically or in a config file).

```
Legitimate MAC Cloning Example
==============================

Computer              WiFi         ^    =radio=   ^          WiFi                 Computer
   A                  Bridge      /|\            /|\       Access Point              B
+------+              +-----+      |              |         +-----+               +------+
|      |MAC A    MAC x|     |MAC A'|              |   MAC P |     | MAC y   MAC B |      |
|      +--------------+     +------+              +---------+     +---------------+      |
|      | Eth      Eth |     |   Antenna          Antenna    |     | Eth       Eth |      |
+------+              +-----+                               +-----+               +------+
                               ^                                               ^
                               |                                                |
                       Bridge clones MAC-A                      Traffic from "Computer A" now shows
                       on its wireless interface                up using Computer A's MAC address, 
                                                                because the Bridge cloned it.
```